# Rails Error - "cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext" on Windows 7, 64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt

I am on Windows 7 64 bit, and I am running Ruby 2.3.3 and Rails 5.1.2. I am coming across this error with my RoR project when attempting to create a new user on my website:

> "LoadError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create" "cannot load
>   such file -- bcrypt_ext"

I have come across this and similar solutions through Google searching:

> "Firstly uninstall bcrypt and bcrypt-ruby by running these two
>   commands: gem uninstall bcrypt and gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby Install
>   it again with gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby In your Gemfile write
>   gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.5', :require => 'bcrypt' Run bundle install"

However, when I attempt to run `gem uninstall bcrypt` in my console I receive this error message:

> "$ gem uninstall bcrypt ERROR:  While executing gem ...
>   (Gem::DependencyRemovalException)
>       Uninstallation aborted due to dependent gem(s)"

I believe this is due to my Devise gem. When I run `gem list bcrypt` in console I receive this output:

> "bcrypt (3.1.11 x86-mingw32)"
>
> My rails app came with this line commented out in my gem file:
>
> "# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
>
> ## gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11'"

I have tried uncommenting it back into the code, and when I do so the Rails Server fails to load and lists this error in console:

```
C:\Users\James\Desktop\rails_app>rails s
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ex
t (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-
x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-
x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2
/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
        from C:/Users/James/Desktop/rails_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (
required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3
/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:129:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3
/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:129:in `block in perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3
/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3
/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/li
b/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/li
b/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3
/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3
/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3
/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

At this point, I'm out of ideas. Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall `bcrypt-ruby` before uninstalling `bcrypt`, as this is the dependent gem.

This can be done as so:

```
gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby
gem uninstall bcrypt
gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. That solution did not work for me. I am still receiving this error in console when attempting the gem uninstall: 

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyRemovalException)
    Uninstallation aborted due to dependent gem(s)

I'm still thinking this is due to the Devise gem, but I'd love to consider other options/opinions.

Answer (score 0):

try the following steps which worked for me:

1. remove anything related to brypt from you Gemfile
2. Enter the following information into your Gemfile

gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'

3. Run 'bundle install' at the root of your project and it should work.

For some reason when you point it to the git page it worked for me.